# Getting Error like "Error in Export Module " When I try to import or export module from vs code to vba macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-code

I'm new in **VBA**.

So I want to use VS Code as my editor to code my project VBA.

The problem is when I try to click on "Import - VBA" [image] on VS code and I get the error like this

[image]

I already tick on "Enable all Macro" on Excel file but the error appear again.

[image]

Here is my code.

[image]

Indeed, can you help me please

Comment: You cannot just paste VBA code into Visual Studio - it's not the same language.

Comment: Who told you that what you try is possible? I also like to have money like Bill Gates, but...

Comment: I already install XVBA on vs code to manipulate VBA from  excel and I have seen many tutorial on Youtube to execute code vba on vscode

Comment: To "execute VBA code" it is something different. To use VBA code as you try, I  am afraid it is not possible. Is what you try part of such a tutorial? I will maybe learn something new...

Comment: Yeah !  Here is link of the tutorial [link video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmFIugafE4U&ab_channel=BetoAeraphe)

Comment: This seems like a question for the VSCode add-in author...